# how to return the number alone of count(*) value in mysql query

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, count

Im new to mysql, I want to query a db and get the total amount of rows, I'm using SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db but what I get back is [ { 'COUNT(*)': 18 } ], how do i just get the value (18) by itself so that I can display it on the front end, my cod is below, thank you.

```
connection.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db', (err, rows) => {

    connection.release();

    if(!err) {
        rows = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows))
        console.log(rows)

        res.render('home', {rows})
    }else {
        console.log(err)
    }

})
```

Comment: you could do `SELECT COUNT(*) as totalRecords FROM db...` and then `rows[0]['totalRecords']`

Comment: As Sudhir says, you will always have an array as a result because SQL needs to indicate which column you result is in. Just take the result from that array that mysql returns, and display it as you want. ```console.log(rows[0]["COUNT()"])``` should do the trick as you want to have the first row, and the column COUNT() to be displayed.